# Meteor AutoForm: How to update schema values with array of sub-documents?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I am new to Meteor AutoForm. I want to update player docs with country doc. Below is my code. If I add`{{> afQuickField name="country"}}` in AutoForm it doesn't works. `{{> afQuickField name="name"}}` alone works fine. How do I add entire country docs `(_id,slug,name)` in players country field?

**JS:**

```
CountrySchema = new SimpleSchema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        max: 100,
        index: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        max: 100
    }
});

Player.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Player name",
        index: true
    },
    country: {
        type: [CountrySchema],
        label: "country",
        max: 5,
        index: true,
        autoform: {
            options: function() {
                return Country.find().fetch().map(function(object) {
                    return {
                        label: object.name,
                        value: object._id
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

**HTML:**

```
{{#autoForm id="editplayer" }}
   {{> afQuickField name="name"}}
   {{> afQuickField name="country"}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

I added `SimpleSchema.debug = true;` console log shows `SimpleSchema invalid keys for "editplayer" context`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to render `country` as an array field you could use the [`afArrayField`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#afarrayfield) component:

```
<template name="editPlayer">
    {{#autoForm id="editplayer" collection="Player" type="update" doc=currentPlayer}}
        {{> afQuickField name="name"}}
        {{> afArrayField name="country"}}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

---

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    AutoForm.debug();
    Template.editPlayer.helpers({
        currentPlayer: function () {
            return Player.findOne();
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        let country = {slug: 'austria', name: 'Austria'};
        Country.insert(country);
        Player.insert({name: 'Matthias Eckhart', country: [country]});
    });
}

Player = new Mongo.Collection("player");
Country = new Mongo.Collection("country");

CountrySchema = new SimpleSchema({
    slug: {
        type: String,
        max: 100,
        index: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        max: 100
    }
});

Player.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Player name",
        index: true
    },
    country: {
        type: [CountrySchema],
        label: "country",
        max: 5,
        index: true,
        autoform: {
            options: function () {
                return Country.find().map((object) => ({label: object.name, value: object._id}));
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

Please note, that I assumed you want to update a `player` document. Therefore, I set the attribute `doc=currentPlayer` and specified a `player` document via the `currentPlayer` helper function. If you set the data context, for instance via the [`data` function](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#rendering-templates-with-data) in your [Iron Router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router) route, you could use `doc=this`.

---

If you want to have a simple select form, your current data structure may require a *workaround*. The problem is that `[CountrySchema]` does not expand into proper schema keys. As a result, you need to explicitly specify the full schema and convert the selected options using [AutoForm hooks](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks) and a Meteor helper function (`currentPlayer`):

```
<template name="editPlayer">
    {{#autoForm id="editplayer"  collection="Player" type="update" doc=currentPlayer}}
        {{> afQuickField name="name"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="country"}}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

---

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    AutoForm.debug();
    Template.editPlayer.helpers({
        currentPlayer: function () {
            let player = Player.findOne();
            if (player) player.country = _.map(player.country, (country) => country._id);
            return player;
        }
    });
    var playerUpdateHook = {
        before: {
            update: function (doc) {
                doc['$set'].country = _.map(doc['$set'].country, (countryId) => Country.findOne({_id: countryId}));
                return doc;
            }
        }
    };
    AutoForm.addHooks('editplayer', playerUpdateHook);
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        let country = {slug: 'austria', name: 'Austria'};
        let countryId = Country.insert(country);
        country = Country.findOne({_id: countryId});
        Player.insert({name: 'Matthias Eckhart', country: [country]});
    });
}

Player = new Mongo.Collection("player");
Country = new Mongo.Collection("country");

CountrySchema = new SimpleSchema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        max: 100,
        index: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        max: 100
    }
});

Player.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Player name",
        index: true
    },
    country: {
        type: [CountrySchema],
        label: "country",
        max: 5,
        index: true
    },
    'country.$': {
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            options: function () {
                return Country.find().map((object) => ({label: object.name, value: object._id}));
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot @Matthias Eckhart. I need to display country in select box but it comes in text box. Can you **PLEASE** let me know to make it select box. http://i.imgur.com/dLsECxZ.png

Comment: Hi @Matthias Eckhart.  I tried updated answer. but i am getting validation error. Can you help me? http://i.imgur.com/dGmn3se.png?1

Comment: @BlueBells Your hook is not set up properly. You need to convert your `_id` values to objects.

Comment: Yes @Matthias Eckhart solved by `AutoForm.addHooks`. Thanks a lot again. you are my saviour